# how to convert 12 hour to 24 hour in r

Tags: r

I split the time from 2018-12-31 11:45:00 AM to 2018-12-31 and 11:45:00 aAM successfully.

However, I get difficulty that convert "11:45:00 AM" to 24 hours.

I know there are several ways to do that, for example, the most popular way is to use `strptime` and put `format="%I:%M:%S %p`. I did that several times and made double checked again and again... but still get N/A in my column. Here is, crimeData is my dataset name, toSplitHrs contains time which is "11:45:00 AM" just like what mentioned:

```r
crimeData$toSplitHrs = strptime(crimeData$SplitHrs, format="%I:%M:%S %p")
```

```r
Police.Beats    SplitMs SplitHrs year month days hours mins sec toSplitHrs
1           28 2018-12-31 11:45:00 2018    12   31    11   45  00       <NA>
2          177 2018-12-31 11:42:00 2018    12   31    11   42  00       <NA>
3          233 2018-12-31 11:30:00 2018    12   31    11   30  00       <NA>
4           91 2018-12-31 11:30:00 2018    12   31    11   30  00       <NA>
5           73 2018-12-31 11:30:00 2018    12   31    11   30  00       <NA>
6          232 2018-12-31 11:27:00 2018    12   31    11   27  00       <NA>
```

but still, I got N/A result from that...
Also, this dataset contains over 10k observations, I really cannot change them one by one...any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: can you post a reproducible example using `dput(head(crimeData))` ?

Comment: have you tried `strptime(crimeData$SplitHrs, format="%F %r")` ?

Comment: @RonakShah I update my head...thank you so much for your attention

Comment: @Cath Thank you for your suggestion. I tried this one but still get N/A, weird

Answer (score 2):

You can try the format `%r` for the time, taking into account the am/pm specification (see `?strptime`):

```
strptime("2018-12-31 11:45:00 am", format="%F %r")
#[1] "2018-12-31 11:45:00 CET"
strptime("2018-12-31 11:45:00 pm", format="%F %r")
#[1] "2018-12-31 23:45:00 CET"
```

Comment: `%r` is equivalent to `%I:%M:%S %p.`, OP's attempt works too on your input `strptime("2018-12-31 11:45:00 am", format="%F %I:%M:%S %p")`

Comment: I don't think that's an issue. OP mentioned that they have split date and time separately.  They are now dealing only with time. So `strptime("11:45:00 am", format="%I:%M:%S %p")` and `strptime("11:45:00 am", format="%r")` both work. OP has tried the former one which resulted into `NA`.

Comment: @RonakShah fair enough, I missed that part: lack of representative example... so maybe a local problem ?

Comment: do I need to put actual data as the argument? The dataset contains over 10K observations

Comment: Here is, I have split the original TIME column as TWO parts, one part for hours, like "11:45:00 AM", another part like "2018-12-31". so that I only need to format the first part